# Generic methods returning a collection giving an Unsafe type cast warning

Tags: java, generics, types

When I define a method to return a class of Type , shouldn't I be able to override the method with any type that extends Base? Take the following example:

MultiEntryModel.java (parent class)

```
protected abstract <T extends Model> List<T> getDataList();
```

ProgramData.java

```
public class ProgramData extends MultiEntryModel {
    ...
       @Override
        protected List<Program> getDataList() {
            return programs;
        }
}
```

Program.java

```
public class Program extends Model {
   ...
}
```

I'm getting an unsafe type cast warning in Programs.java, even though I'm returning a List containing objects of type Program, which extends the Model class, just as indicated by the method signature in the base class `<T extends Model>`. Why?

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, along with the exact and complete error message. There is no cast at all in the code you posted.

Comment: There is no casting. The warning comes up in Programs.java at the point where the method is being overridden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
protected abstract <T extends Model> List<T> getDataList();
```

This means that a List will be returned which has to be safe for *any* `T`. For example:

```
List<SomeModel> someModelList = thing.getDataList();
```

If the list you're returning is a `List<Program>`, this is going to be unsafe - because you can add a `SomeModel` into that list, and/or you can try to get a `SomeModel` from the list. If `Program` is a subtype/supertype of `Program`, just one of those operations is safe; otherwise, they are both unsafe.

Don't define the type variable on the method - put it on the class:

```
abstract class TheClass<T extends Model> {
  protected abstract List<T> getDataList();
}

class ProgramClass extends TheClass<Program> {
  protected List<Program> getDataList() { return programs; }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting and well explained. Thank you! :)

Comment: The caller is not even bound to the existing subclasses of `Model`. With a signature of `<T extends Model> List<T> getDataList()`, I could even write, `List<? extends ExecutorService> list = getDataList();`, expecting you to return a list of instances of `Model` subclasses which implement `ExecutorService`…